# Iframe in Typo3 not loading

Tags: html, iframe, typo3

I'm trying to include a booking frame into our website using an iframe within a html content element. However, the particular website does not load. Instead a white area is shown.

I am trying to include the following page:
https://booking.cinetixx.de/frontend/index.html?bgswitch=false&cinemaId=1164899599#/eventList/1164899599

I've tried calling a different website and this worked:

It appears the problem is related to the specific website I am trying to include.

You can see the test page on https://www.kurtheaterhennef.de/index.php?id=179

Comment: actually, your test page seems to work for me :S Do you have some browser configuration (some blocker plugin or something similar)?

Answer (score 0):

Your test page worked for me. The iframe is loading there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome.

Comment: It does work for me, too. (MacOS: Firefox, Safari, Chrome)